# Spring batch scaling in not happening in Pivotal Cloud foundary

Tags: spring-batch, cloud-foundry

I have one sample spring batch application(Remote Partitioning). Here I have master/slave step configuration when deployed in PCF both slave and master, Its taking same processing time even if I am increasing instance of slave.
Can someone help what may be the problem whether we can scale my job just by increasing instance or not in PCF? 
I found one answer from @Michael Minella ([Spring Batch and Pivotal Cloud Foundry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35510211/spring-batch-and-pivotal-cloud-foundry?rq=1)) and basically what I understood is , just by increasing the instance should scale the job.Let me know if more information is needed.

Comment: Please provide your configuration.

Comment: Hi @MichaelMinella , I used your application example only(https://github.com/mminella/LearningSpringBatch/tree/master/src/remotePartitioning) :) just to check how we can scale just by increasing instance of slave.

Comment: That isn't intended for PCF.  Try this one instead: https://github.com/mminella/S3JDBC

Comment: Thanks @MichaelMinella , just I want you to know , I did minor change(binded rabbitmq service to app) and able to run the application.I had increased the slave instance to 12 but processing time is still the same even if running the application with 4 instance. And more interestingly all CPU is being used but no difference in processing time.

Comment: Are you sure the `Partitioner` is returning different data for each partition?

Comment: I think so @MichaelMinella because as you are logging message like reading from XXX to YYY in reader if you remember. I can see different partition in slave log(PCF)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151516/discussion-between-rocky-and-michael-minella).

Comment: Please join the Spring Batch Gitter channel for chat: github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch